# Display 404 document from htaccess after sending 404 header in PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In PHP I use the following code to indicate page not found:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");exit();
```

In `.htaccess` file I have the following line to handle 404 custom document:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Now when I send the PHP 404 header I expect it to show the custom `404.html` defined in `.htaccess` but instead it shows a message "this link appears to be broken". So it doesn't show the custom 404 page and if I remove the line from `.htaccess` it still won't display the regular 404 page of the server and shows also the broken link message.

So how to make it show the 404 page when I send the header in PHP?

Comment: Looks like the ErrorDocument directive is not working. Try `RewriteEngine On` `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`.

Comment: I already have the rewriteengine on line...thanks :)

Comment: `RewriteEngine` (mod_rewrite) and `ErrorDocument` (core) are unrelated. FWIW, it sounds like you were seeing the browser's default 404 error document, which you will likely see (depending on the browser) when you don't send an empty response body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the custom error document denoted by `ErrorDocument` isn't processed unless the URL processing pipeline can't find a file (or a handler) that the URL points to. In you case, the processing pipeline **does** find a file, your php file, thus it never reaches a 404 on its own so the `ErrorDocument` is never applied.

When apache uses the php handler to run your php file, and your **php file decides to return a 404**, you not only need to provide the 404 response code, but the HTML error document as well. You don't see the default apache error document because apache never thinks the request is a 404 (it handed the request off to your php file). So you need to do something like this:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
include('404.html');
exit();
```

Comment: that did it! Didn't know how to do this for years..glad i asked here...thanks Jon very much :D

Answer (score 0):

you just send a 404 code to your browser try to redirect to your error 404 page

```
header('location: http://youdomain.com/404.html'); exit;
```

Comment: And what if I'd want to output the error document without redirecting? E.g. not showing to the user that there exists a php script.

Comment: so what's the use of the 404 header if I can just redirect to 404??

Comment: @MichaelSamuel the 404 header returns an HTTP response code, which tells whatever is on the other end that the request URL was "Not Found". You can redirect to the error document, but the code returned from that will be a **200**, which would erroneously make whatever on the other end think that a bad URL was actually a good one, regardless of the content in the response.